# How to use angular2's http with other port than application host port?

Tags: asp.net, http, angular

I have a ASP.NET solution with both a web project that hosts my angular2 app and a web api project.

Both projects are setup as startup projects and are running on different ports (`45365` for  the web project and `20234` for the web api project).

Let´s say I have a web api controller that exposes `/api/values` which is currently accessible via `http://localhost:20234/api/values`

How can I access this in my angular2 web app? If I try

```
this.http.get("api/values")
```

it tries to access `http://localhost:45365/api/values` which is not desired. However, I want it to call `http://localhost:20234/api/values` without specifying the whole url including domain to make my service work even when the app is published to a public server with an other domain than `localhost`.

How do I tell `http.get()`to use `20234` as port number?

Comment: use the full address.

Comment: basically change the get to this.http.get("http://localhost:45365/api/values")

Comment: thanks, but I explicitly asked for a solution without hardwiring `localhost` into my services

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
constructor(private location:Location, private locationStrategy:LocationStrategy) {}

someMethod() {
  var base = this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref();
  // replace port

  this.location.prepareExternalUrl(base + 'xxx');
}
```

You can implement this in a service that forwards to `Http` so you don't need to repeat it.

(not tested)

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for. Thanks.