# Ionic 2 client files on one port, API endpoints on different port

Tags: webpack, ionic2

I have an ASP.NET Core server set up on port 1512, and my Ionic 2 dev server is running on port 1513. I want to be able to open localhost:1513 so I get the live-reload features of the dev server, but when my api requests are called I want them to use port 1512 so they retrieve from the backend server.

I had this set up with webpack and angular alone, but with Ionic 2 I am struggling to get this to work properly.

Comment: How are you making your api calls? You'll just have to use the correct port when making the calls.

Comment: `this.http.get("api/account/userinfo")`

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625179/how-to-use-angular2s-http-with-other-port-than-application-host-port), and the comments to the question.

For local development, you can change

```
this.user = this.http.get("api/account/userinfo")
```

into

```
this.user = this.http.get("localhost:1512/api/account/userinfo")
```